# REC_CATCH_EXCEPTION error (Exception is caught when Exception is not thrown)

Tags: java, spotbugs

I am seeing a weird behaviour where I added some code inside a `try` block and now I am getting the spotbug error `REC_CATCH_EXCEPTION` (Exception is caught when Exception is not thrown) for some reason.

So basically originally, my code was something like this:

```
while (true) {
    try {
        if (something()) {
            doSomething();
        } else if (somethingElse()) {
            doSomethingElse();
        } else {
            do();
        }
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        System.out.println(ex.toString());
    }
}
```

And when I run the code above, I do not get any spotbug errors. However when I add the new `else if` block I get the `REC_CATCH_EXCEPTION` error. So my new code, where I am seeing the error, is something like this:

```
while (true) {
    try {
        if (something()) {
            doSomething();
        } else if (somethingElse()) {
            doSomethingElse();
        } else if (someOtherThing()) {
            doSomeOtherThing();
        } else {
            do();
        }
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        System.out.println(ex.toString());
    }
}
```

Nothing really changed other than the addition of the `doSomeOtherThing()` method. So I am not exactly sure why I am seeing this error. Also, please note that the `doSomeOtherThing()` method does not throw or catch any exceptions inside of it.